# MAF with class inside DLL passing to host

Tags: c#, .net, add-in, maf

I'm developing a MAF application which, in a DLL contains a class. The problem is, when one of the methods exposed by one of the AddIns uses this class. Example:

```
class A
{
    Property_1
    Property_2

    Method_X()
}
```

And my AddIn has a method which use class A

```
MyAddIn.Set(class A);
```

So, with this, where must I place the DLL in the pipeline? Or how should I proceed with this scenario?

When the proyect start, the warnings of the AddInStore.Update() method throws messages like: unable to connect a part of a canalization...

So, there is an article [this](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/9396/creating-extensible-applications-with-maf/) which says "There are many other capabilities MAF provides such as versioning, passing collections and WPF visuals, passing non-serializable types, etc.". But I can't find an example.

EDIT:

Thanks to Panos for this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clraddins/archive/2007/02/27/restrictions-on-contracts.aspx) about the restrictions on contracts. And after more research I've found this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zifengh/archive/2007/01/24/clr-addin-model-in-paint-net-10-data-type-contract.aspx) which, through the Paint.NET proyect, shows how to use data types in the host without referencing.

After reading both sources, I know that this is what I'm looking for. But I can't understand it yet.

As a final petition, can someone please provide me code example? Just to finally get it.

Thanks.

Comment: Before you continue with System.Addin, I would advise you to have a look at other add-in engines, like MEF for example. MEF is quite popular and has a low learning curve. With System.AddIn you will need to invest a lot of time to get the hang of it. Note that System.AddIn has the add-in isolation feature (different AppDomain/Processes) which is quite hard to do by yourself and it is probably the only reason to choose it. If you are looking for versioning have a look at Autofac + MEF. Finally if you only need add-in capabilities, MEF should be more than enough. Regards.

Comment: Hi, I already look at MEF, however, the main reason for using MAF is updating the plugins without shutting down the application, this is crucial. As far as I know, this is not possible with MEF. My app is already capable of updating the AddIn.

Answer (score 2):

You should study these [guidelines](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clraddins/archive/2007/02/27/restrictions-on-contracts.aspx) on what types are allowed in the contracts assembly.

Basically you should not reference the dll you mention in the pipeline (contracts, adapters and views) because this way you can leak types from the host to the add-in. This means that you will lose versioning because all pipeline segments are referencing the same assembly. What this means is that if the add-in is referencing v.1 of the assembly and the contract is referencing v.2, both versions will be loaded and an InvalidCasrtException will be thrown.

A solution to this is to create an interface based on class A and make it a contract. Then your add-in can provide the implementation. Thiw way you will not lose versioning.

Regards,

Panos

Comment: Thanks for your help. Very resourceful. I edited the question to keep it updated. Once again, Thanks.